# Weirdest sql server bug happening on production

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, database, security

Like any other web application I got web application with aspx forms and sql database, hosted on amazon.

from last month a weird thing start happening, when someone submit changes from web form, changes got saved in database BUT overnight the values roll back to old values. No automatic process are there, no nightly procs or backup, no web account is hacked, nothing, it just goes back to old values magically in database.

I did put a log table with the affected table to track down each transaction, what time , who did it etc, and found out that changes happen on different times on a day (cant wireshark), and also it happen to random fields (columns) on the table.

for example :
today i change "ontime", "offitme", "foodorderFlag" , "activeFlag" in one of my table, tomorrow i saw that ontime, offtime and activeflag changed back to there old values.

Then i again changed them all, and next day only ontime and foodorderFlag changed back to old values.

MY LOGS:
i got an Audit table which get an entry via trigger, when company table got inserted, updated or deleted.
[image]

Above you see the highlighted are the log for company table when values updated by web form in company table (normal process). datemodified and modifiedbyuserid are automatically updated behind the scene and are not direct fields on web form.

NOW

see below

[image]

highlighted above are: how the values changed back to old values in company table at midnight.. note that datemodified and modifiedbyuserid is not rolled back this time, means this change is not form web form. looks like external source using the same login but not web forms. Also if this is changed by system or sql, the user will be like amazona\administrator or sa etc.. but that is not the case here.

Any idea , what could it be , attack i think now ?

ALL FIXED
Its all because I am lazy careless slacker. I did migration couple of months back and rather then running script in a new window i did it underneath an existing stored proc (on production :o), and forgot to delete it. whenever that stored proc is being called it was running migration script as well, resetting values. SORRY for wasting your time guys.

Comment: It's really strange. My first reaction after reading the question: "Is this guy telling the truth?"

Comment: Is there an uncommitted transaction that is being rolled back at some point in time?  So the values are applied, but because the transaction hasn't been committed, at some future time there is a rollback that undoes your values?

Comment: What isolation level do you use when accessing that table in question? A READ_UNCOMMITED isolation level or a WITH NOLOCK hint would return uncommitted data. If that's the case Jane might be spot on with the assumption of a transaction roll back.

Comment: Are you certain it's being rolled back? is it just being overwritten by a normal transaction? You need to give more details about how your logging worked and what it captured. If your web app captures user names you need to try to add that to your log (which can be hard if your web app just runs under a single service account)

Comment: A normal transaction _might_ be replacing the new values with the old values, but it's more likely that they'd have a different set of values, especially if you're talking about "ontime" and "offtime".  But of course it's entirely possible in a multiuser situation :)

Comment: You could set up some triggers in the database to track more info on changes.

Comment: If it's a transaction being rolled back somewhere, you can find it, first, by running `dbcc opentran();` in separate connection (from SSMS, for example). Also, query your updated table right after you did it, but from a different connection, and add a `with (readcommitted)` hint, just in case.

Comment: I also laughed on client and my PM when first told about this.Thanks guys for pondering. No i am not using any transactions. and i did checked open transactions there are none. we had a brute force attack on our sql server in may, whihc is common on amazon instances. This thing happening after that. i will update log in my question. btw, i changed sa password all other sql user passwords plus website login passwords. and doing on more test today. Lets see if values change back again or not.

Comment: ALL FIXED
Its all because I am lazy careless slacker. I did migration couple of months back and rather then running script in a new window i did it underneath an existing stored proc (on production :o), and forgot to delete it. whenever that stored proc is being called it was running migration script as well, resetting values. SORRY for wasting your time guys.

Comment: @user1908862 I think you need to post that you are a "lazy careless slacker" as an answer, and then accept it. ;-)